# JavaScript functions disappear when I update content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, load

Please help me, I have tried to find an explanation to this problem for half of my working day.

When I update div-tag with new content by using jquery the JavaScript functionality disappears in the updated content? How do I resolve this in the simplest way?

```
function liveFeed(){
    var country = $('#country').val();
    //var time = new Date().getTime()
    $('.post').load('/includes/public/livefeed.php?country=' + country);        
    }
window.setInterval(liveFeed, 10000);
```

Comment: Without knowing how your javascript content is hooked up, or what is inside the code you're loading, we'll have a hard time helping with this one.

Comment: More code or a working example would help.

Comment: This question is asked, in one form or another, at least daily.

Comment: PHP file downloads data from the database, some information is hidden. You need to click a link to view hidden from the div tag. Here is the following code that I want to work when I have updated the div tag using the LiveFeed() function shown above

$(document).ready(function showbox() {
  $('a.showbox').click(function() {
  var ID = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#viewbox' + ID).toggle();   
  return false;
  });
  });

Comment: Instead of `$('a.showbox').click(function() ...)` use `$('a.showbox').live('click', function() ...)`

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what your "Javascript functionality" is.  Generally, it disappears for a perfectly good reason: the DOM elements themselves are thrown out and replaced by new ones.

For event handling, you can use the jQuery `.delegate()` or `.live()` methods to bind your event handlers. For other stuff (like datepickers or dialogs) you have to re-run the code that sets them up.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing everything, I would guess that you simply need to rebind the Javascript function after loading the new content.